# Axios network error ,front: reactnative ,backend :springboot localhost server and my phone via USB

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, rest, axios, jwt

i am working on a project using springboot  as a backend with jwt configuration and this is an example of a url :  Post "http://localhost:8095/users/signin", for the frontend i am using react native ( i am new to it ) for mobile application i ve installed axios, spinner, and async and i did this : [this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUs4f.png)    [tokenservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy4iP.png)[loginscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V54K.png)and finally [config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XmGN.png)..and i am testing  this project with my phone via USB (developer mode) but i always get axios network error altho the configuration of the token in the backend allows the methods post,get etc...and i did the @CrossOrgin="*".please help me

i fellowed this tutorial on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXVJYXd3C8k&t=1233s and i ve searched many videos i ve added this (      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true")
adn in android/app/src/main/androidmanifest.xml and in ios/project/info.plist i added this line right before   : 

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

  and this is my package.json :     .

i really don't know what to do..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BASEURL already has a '/' in the end, so if your calling the signup, you can't call it '/signup' but instead 'signup' only.

Comment: i ve corrected that now it takes lot of time to reload but i still get this : axioserror:network error  ..i am testing with my mobile using  USB..is there anyone i can fix the error

Comment: Have you tested the link outside of the app? What results does it give in the browser?

Comment: it works for the webapp (using react js on port 3000 ) but when it comes to my phone i am testing the react native nothin happens

Comment: i mean i only get axioserror :network error

Comment: can you give repo acess to this? to help you further ? If possible show me the app.json file.

Comment: another thing to add : you said in the post you are using : http://localhost:8095/users/signin , in the app i don't see you using the '/users' part, is that normal ? how are you testing the api in the web?